# How to resolve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in Android Studio using Fragments

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, memory

This is my first time programming for mobile.  My app has been crashing when I switch from one fragment to another.  In logcat after one crash it showed me "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" among a litany of other things.  I think it's because my first fragment has a photo and the second does as well.  Is there a simple way to make sure that a fragment is out of memory once another is loaded? I've looked around quite a bit but haven't found any straightforward answers.

Here's the code for switching fragments as is...

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
     int id = item.getItemId();
     Fragment fragment;

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        fragment = new LandingPageFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_documents) {
        fragment = new DocumentsPageFragment();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_messages) {
        fragment = new MessagesFragment();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_admin) {
        fragment = new AdministrationFragment();
    }
    else{
        fragment = new LandingPageFragment();
    }


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent,fragment).commit();
    this.prevFragment = fragment;

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_new);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Posting the stacktrace will help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way of knowing when `OutOfMemoryError` get's thrown, but the important thing you have to do is making sure you are not loading very big images to your `ImageViews`. The best thing you could do is scale the images down before loading them into your `ImageView`s. This fixes the OOM issue. You can use the code in this guide to scale down the images: [Android developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Thank you, turns out that was the problem.  I didn't think of it because I only had one other image on a landing page but it was very high res so it took up a disproportionately large amount of memory.

Comment: I'm glad I've helped you. Can you please accept my answer?